# trying to do SELECT in php but i get

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I got a nifty little bit of code set to run along and find me information when I give it a certain KittenID but its not working at all, I am sad. And oh so tired, Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong? and yes I do have:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
//If statements:

//find:
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
if(isset($_POST['Find'])) 
{
            $connection = mysql_connect("ocelot.aul.fiu.edu","userName","password");

            // Check connection
            if (!$connection)
        {
            echo "Connection failed: " . mysql_connect_error();
        }
            else
            {  
                //select a database
                $dbName="spr15_xgotz001";
                $db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbName, $connection); 

                //confirm connection to database
                if (!$db_selected)
                {
                    die ('Can\'t use $dbName : ' . mysql_error());
                }
                else
                {
                    $result = mysql_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM Kittenz WHERE KittenID =<?php$_POST[KittenID]?>;)

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                    $Name = $row['Name'];
                    $KittenID = $row['KittenID'];
                    $KittenAge = $row['KittenAge'];
                    $Email = $row['Email'];
                    $Comments = $row['Comments'];
                    $Gender = $row['Gender'];
                    $Personality = $row['Personality'];
                    $Activity = $row['Activity']; 
                    echo $row['Comments'];

                    }
                }
            }

            mysql_close($connection);
}


?>
```

Comment: _'its not working '_ is not a problem descripton. Describe what the code is supposed to do, what it catually does and post any error messages you have.

Comment: I kinda blanked out, this is due in 8 hours sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$result = mysql_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM Kittenz WHERE KittenID = " .$_POST['KittenID']);
```

instead of

```
$result = mysql_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM Kittenz WHERE KittenID =<?php$_POST[KittenID]?>;)
```

*Note: Please use mysqli_* for your future projects

Answer (score 0):

You need to privide more context. How are you setting the $_GET['id'].. is it in fact being stored as $_GET['KittenID'] (e.g. https://yoursite.com?view&KittenID=1). If so...

You can set a variable and declare the 'KittenID'

```
$kittenid = $_POST['KittenID'];

$result = mysql_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM Kittenz WHERE KittenID = $kittenid");
```

I suggest providing more context. What error are you getting? What do your parameters look like?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$result = mysql_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM Kittenz WHERE KittenID = " .$_SERVER['KittenID']);
```

instead of

```
$result = mysql_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM Kittenz WHERE KittenID =<?php$_POST[KittenID]?>;)
```